# Performance issue due to recursivity usage

Tags: java

I have a performance issue when I execute my code below. It is using recursive function. For now, it takes me 10670 ms to run it. Can someone help me to improve it? I am using java 8 but as I am not familiar yet with it, I did not implement it with java 8. I red online, it says that java 8 can improve performance but can make performance as well depending of the amount of data you manipulate. Thanks all

```
public static void RemoveDuplicateData(List<VariableDataGroup> variableDataGroups) {
        if (variableDataGroups == null) {
            return;
        }
        for (VariableDataGroup varDataGroup : variableDataGroups) {
            RemoveDuplicateData(varDataGroup.getOrDataList());
            if (varDataGroup.getAndDataList() != null) {
                removeAnyDuplicateAndBlankCodesFromAndDataList(varDataGroup);
            }

            if (varDataGroup.getNotDataList() != null) {
                removeAnyDuplicateAndBlankCodesFromNotDataList(varDataGroup);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void removeAnyDuplicateAndBlankCodesFromAndDataList(VariableDataGroup varDataGroup) {
        for (int x = (varDataGroup.getAndDataList().size()-1) ; x >= 0; x--) {
            if (varDataGroup.getAndDataList().get(x) == null || varDataGroup.getAndDataList().get(x).isEmpty())
            {
                varDataGroup.getAndDataList().remove(x);
            } else {
                for (int y = 0; y < x; y++) {
                    if (varDataGroup.getAndDataList().get(x).equals(varDataGroup.getAndDataList().get(y))) {
                        varDataGroup.getAndDataList().remove(x);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void removeAnyDuplicateAndBlankCodesFromNotDataList(VariableDataGroup varDataGroup) {
        for (int x = (varDataGroup.getNotDataList().size()-1) ; x >= 0; x--) {
            if (varDataGroup.getNotDataList().get(x) == null    || varDataGroup.getNotDataList().get(x).isEmpty())
            {
                varDataGroup.getNotDataList().remove(x);
            } else {
                for (int y = 0; y < x; y++) {
                    if (varDataGroup.getNotDataList().get(x).equals(varDataGroup.getNotDataList().get(y))) {
                        varDataGroup.getNotDataList().remove(x);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class VariableDataGroup {    
        private String appearingData = "";
        private boolean dataFound ;
        private List<String> notDataList = new ArrayList();
        private List<String> andDataList = new ArrayList();
        private List<VariableGroup> orDataList = new ArrayList();
        ...
    }
```

Thanks Andy Turner and everyone for your help and advice. Here is what I do then.

```
private static void removeDuplicateAndEmptyData(VariableDataGroup varDataGroup) {
        Set<String> dedupedAndDataSet = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        List<String> andDataList = varDataGroup.getAndDataList();
        Set<String> dedupedNotDataSet = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        List<String> notDataList = varDataGroup.getNotDataList();

        for (String s : andDataList) {
          if (s != null && !s.isEmpty()) {
            dedupedAndDataSet.add(s);
          }
        }
        andDataList.clear();
        andDataList.addAll(dedupedAndDataSet);

        for (String s : notDataList) {
          if (s != null && !s.isEmpty()) {
            dedupedNotDataSet.add(s);
          }
        }
        notDataList.clear();
        notDataList.addAll(dedupedNotDataSet);
    }

    public static void RemoveDuplicateData(List<VariableDataGroup> variableDataGroups) {
        if (variableDataGroups == null) {
            return;
        }
        for (VariableDataGroup varDataGroup : variableDataGroups) {
            RemoveDuplicateData(varDataGroup.getOrDataList());
            if (varDataGroup.getAndDataList() != null) {
                removeDuplicateAndEmptyData(varDataGroup);
            }

            if (varDataGroup.getNotDataList() != null) {
                removeDuplicateAndEmptyData(varDataGroup);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: No, we can't really help you, because you've not given any information to go on. We can't reproduce your performance because we don't have the data. 10 seconds might be really good, if you're processing a shed-ton of data. One thing I would say is that you'd be better of using `Set`s to deduplicate the data, rather than linearly scanning through the lists.

Comment: You should take a look at streams and more specifically parallelStreams().

Comment: @AlexPapageorgiou possibly, but plain old sets would be a better place to start, as they are much simpler. As in, change `List<String> notDataList = new ArrayList()` to `Set<String> notDataList = new LinkedHashSet<>()`, and there will be no duplicates in the first place (you'd still have to filter nulls and empty strings; although you could just make sure those are never inserted).

Comment: Java 8 or not has nothing to do with the performance of that code. Amount of data and/or the algorithm of the code does. For the sake of your code, I do hope all the lists are `ArrayList`, not `LinkedList`, because performance of `get(int)` sucks for `LinkedList`. You should use iterators. Also, I hope all those `getXxxDataList()` calls are simple getters, and not copying/wrapping of internal lists for encapsulation purposes, because that would kill performance too given how often you make those calls.

Answer (score 0):

As I commented above, it is hard to offer much help, as we don't know anything about the amount of data you are processing.

However, you would be well served to use `Set`s instead of `List`s to do your deduplication.

For example, your `removeAnyDuplicateAndBlankCodesFromAndDataList` could be written like this:

```
private static void removeAnyDuplicateAndBlankCodesFromAndDataList(VariableDataGroup varDataGroup) {

    List<String> list = varDataGroup.getAndDataList();

    // Copy the list into the set - this removes duplicates.
    Set<String> deduped = new LinkedHashSet<>(list);
    // Remove the null and empty string, if they are present.
    deduped.remove("");
    deduped.remove(null);

    // Replace the list contents with those of deduped.
    list.clear();
    list.addAll(deduped);
}
```

This simply does a lot less work than with the `List`: `Set`s automatically contain no duplicates, and repeatedly removing single elements from an `ArrayList` is quite inefficient (unless it is at the end).

---

Note that everything from the `// Copy the list into the set` comment downwards works on "some list" - so you don't need to duplicate this method for the `not` list, you can simply change the method to accept the `list` as the parameter:

```
private static void removeDuplicates(List<String> list) {
  // ...
}
```

Then invoke like this:

```
if (varDataGroup.getAndDataList() != null) {
  removeDuplicates(varDataGroup.getAndDataList());
}
if (varDataGroup.getNotDataList() != null) {
  removeDuplicates(varDataGroup.getNotDataList());
}
```

(and you could even move the null check into the method, to avoid duplicating that).

---

Of course, you could also just declare the `andDataList` as a `Set` in the first place, then you'd not have to worry about the duplicates (although you would have to somehow filter the null and empty strings).

```
private Set<String> andDataList = new LinkedHashSet<>();
```

Comment: Andy Turner, I have followed your advice and implemented it in my comment above. Can you tell me if it is not what you think? Thank you